# Shall we make AMP page URL SEO friendly or using Query is ok?

Tags: query-string, amp

We are planning to make AMP pages for our dynamic site.

My concern, Is it ok to use QueryString to pass the values or shall we keep URL clean without any parameters.

For example:

`example.com/amp/page.aspx?code=AGR` (With QueryString)

or

`example.com/amp/page/AGR` (SEO Friendly)

Which should I use?

Comment: Is AMP relevant for this question?   I don't think that you are using AMP means that you should use any different logic for choosing your URLs.   We have questions like [Using request_uri instead of Query string affects SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106108/using-request-uri-instead-of-query-string-affects-seo) and [SEO on pages whose content is determined by query string in URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84793/seo-on-pages-whose-content-is-determined-by-query-string-in-url) that should help you.

Comment: Since the page will be rendered by Google server itself, will Google cache the complete URL or leave the query string part. Or any such guideline available for AMP pages.

Comment: AMP or otherwise, the query string is part of the URL.   Removing or changing the query string is generally expected to change the page.  I wouldn't expect Google (or anybody) to cache the version without parameters and expect that to be used for any set of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't feel that AMP pages required seo friendly url, since they are not depending on url. Since, Google never show amp url to users. They make a copy to these pages to their cache. Once a user load the amp then google loads it from cache.

The AMP page url has been used on main page with rel="amphtml" html tag. The url generated here must show your amp page, no matter whether it is seo friendly or not but it must be unique and properly valid with amp validator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to increase your search engine rankings it would be best practise to use an SEO friendly linking structure.

If your objective doesn't include increasing your SEO rankings and you market to your audience in other ways (directly) then any structure is fine.

What is your reason for not using SEO friendly structures, time? It comes down to what you value more, development time or search engine rankings.

Comment: At this point, I don't think there is any direct SEO benefit from rewriting a single parameter into the URL path.   When there are multiple parameters, it can help with ordering.